# Multiprocessing, asyncio, and jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I am trying to run a sub process from a jupyter notebook that requires asyncio. I have distilled it to this basic example that illustrates my issue.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import asyncio

async def test(q, val):

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    q.put(val)


def start1(q, val):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(test(q, val))

def start2(q, val):
    asyncio.ensure_future(test(q, val))

q = Queue()
process = Process(
    target=start,
    args=(q, 123)
)
process.start()
```

when I create the process with

```
target=start1
```

I get

```
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

which is the same as if I were to call start1 directly from the jupyter notebook.

when I create the process with

```
targert=start2
```

the process executes with exitcode 0, indicating no error, but nothing ever gets added to the queue.

Comment: Why not just await `test`?

Comment: @dirn because I need to run it in a sub process.